# How to Use the LinkedIn REST API to Post to Group?

Tags: c#, linkedin-api

I've managed thus far to get the auth code and exchange it to an access token.

Now I only need to know what I do with it (which request I need to send/ or where)
so I can post to a group (and if I have the group name, how do I obtain the group id?)

Specifically, I want to know how to use the REST api in C# to post to a specific group via a request.

Can anybody confirm the answer below?

Comment: Seems like the answer below could be confirmed easily enough by reading the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LinkedIn does not presently expose Groups-related APIs, so this will not be possible.